# Realizar onload una vez

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estoy realizando un `session_destroy` desde dos programas, el primero llama al segundo con una función de `autosubmit` y `onload`, el segundo ejecuta `session_destroy` y `unset_session` y luego vuelve a la primera con un `header`. Mi problema es que al ejecutar la función en la primera y realizar el `header` en la segunda al cargar nuevamente la primera se vuelve a ejecutar la función. He tratado diversos métodos para que realice el `onload` una vez pero aún no logro nada, lo único que pasa es o se cicla con el `onload` o no hace el `onload` y no ejecuta el php.
Entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna función que me permita que haga ese `onload` solo la primer vez que entra en la página?
Este es mi código:

```
<?php 
   $_SESSION['ss'] = 1;
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
 function loadLytebox(id) {
     var ss = '<?php echo $_SESSION['ss'] ?>'; 
     if (!ss) {
       function formAutoSubmit () {
         var frm = document.getElementById("destroy");
         frm.submit();
       }
       window.onload = formAutoSubmit;
   }
   else    {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Esta es una respuesta del servidor ingles: [Onload need to work only once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45339733/7934027)

---

Una forma de lograr lo que deseas es usar la propiedad `name` de `window`, la cual permanecerá después de actualizar.

*Este es un ejemplo de como funcionaria, OJO: Deberás darle clic a ejecutar dos veces, esto te llevara a una pagina, ahí podrás probar bien la funcionalidad.*

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const NOMBRE_WINDOW = "once";

window.onload = function executeOnLoadOnce() {
    if (this.name !== NOMBRE_WINDOW) {
      console.log(this.name)
      this.name = NOMBRE_WINDOW;
    } else {
      // do other stuff
      console.log(this.name)
    }
}
```

La primera vez que cargue la pagina, `window` tendrá un nombre, nosotros cambiaremos ese nombre, para saber que ya se ha cargado una vez. Después comprobaremos si el nombre ha sido cambiado, si es así, entonces la pagina ya se cargo una vez y esta es la segunda, tercera... vez que se ejecuta.

**Personalmente, no creo que hacer algo como esto sea la mejor opción, deberías buscar otra opción para no recurrir a hacer que `onload` "cargue una sola vez"**